# an array of size 37

Tags: c, linux, macos, posix

```
typedef char    __darwin_uuid_string_t[37];
```

this piece of code is excepted from MacOS10.8/user/include/sys/_types.h
I'm wondering
why here is the number 37, but not a power of 2?

Comment: Why do you think it should be a power of 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)** are **36-characters** in length and hence form 37-character strings, including the null-character at the end.

> A UUID is a 16-octet (128-bit) number. In its canonical form, a UUID
>   is represented by 32 hexadecimal digits, displayed in five groups
>   separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36
>   characters (32 digits and four hyphens).

Comment: Should be characters, not bits.

Answer (score 2):

A UUID contains 36 characters plus the terminating 0 byte.

For example (from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)): `550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000`

Answer (score 0):

36-character UUID (32 digits plus 4 '-' separators), plus 0 terminator.

I'm assuming.

Not everything needs to be a power of 2.